# Jasmine test values returned by Ajax during success

Tags: jquery, jasmine-jquery

I've javascript function which makes a Ajax call and writes the value returned to the DOM element
I'm writing the unit test for this function uing jasmine & I'm able to mock the ajax request using it.

Following is the function & unit test

```
myFunction(){
 ......
 ....
  $.ajax(){
     method: "GET"
     url: "/myTest"
     success: function(test){
           $("#htmlElem").html(test);
     }
  };
};

it("specifying response when you need it", function() {

  expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toBe("/myTest);
  ... 
  jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().response({
  "status": 200,
  "contentType": 'text/plain',
  "responseText": 'awesome response'
 });

 myFunction();
 var testVal = $("htmlElem").val();
 expect(testVal).toBe('awesome response');
});
```

The test case fails showing that testVal is empty. As I understand this is happening because the actual ajax call did not execute, so the success call also.
Is my understanding correct? If so, then how can I test the value returned by ajax call is set properly to html element. 
Thanks in advance 
Any p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a callback function to your original AJAX call, then use [Jasmine's asynchronous support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) to test it when the call has completed.

```
myFunction(done) {
  $.ajax(){
     method: "GET"
     url: "/myTest"
     success: function(test){
       $("#htmlElem").html(test);
       done();
     }
  };
};

it("specifying response when you need it", function(done) {    
  // ...
  myFunction(function() {
    var testVal = $("htmlElem").val();
    expect(testVal).toBe('awesome response');
    done();
  });     
});
```